# Max receiving PeerConnections in WebRTC

Tags: javascript, webrtc, janus-gateway

I am using Janus WebRTC server with the VideoRoom plugin. In this plugin, for each user there is 1 sending PeerConnection and *N* receiving PeerConnections so each user can see and hear each other.

How many will be the practical maximum for the receiving PeerConnections in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Chromium has it hardcoded to 500 [here](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/modules/peerconnection/rtc_peer_connection.cc;l=142?q=kMaxPeerConnections)

You will probably hit issues with bandwidth/media encode/decode costs before anything else though.

Comment: only receiving?

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand, what do you mean by receiving? PeerConnections can send/recv at the same time (and the 500 doesn't tie to that).

Comment: In the janus configuration I can set the PeerConnection to only receive.